# How does URL handling work in web.py?

Tags: python, web, web.py

In the following way I bind "hello.py" and "goodbye.py" with the corresponding  classes (functions) and it works. If I go to "0.0.0.0:8080/hello.py" or "0.0.0.0:8080/goodbye.py", I see what I expect to see.

```
import web

urls = ('/(hello.py)', 'hello', '/(goodbye.py)', 'goodbye')

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

class goodbye:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Goodbye, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However, I do not understand why I need to use brackets. If I replace `'/(hello.py)'` by `'/hello.py'`, it does not work. However, in the example [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/url_handling) no brackets are used.

Comment: Actually, why would you have URL such as `/hello.py` or `/goodbye.py`? It is rather unintuitive to type that isn't it? Like what Paul mentioned, you should use `/hello` or `/goodbye` for your URL. My guess on how `/hello.py` could not work is that maybe the browser took it as part of `.com`? I'm not too sure, what's the error message? 404 Not Found?

Answer (score 1):

From the examples that I see (I don't know web.py too well) the get parameters should not be passed in as method parameters, but rather acquired via the web.input method, like so:

```
import web

urls = (

    '/SomePageHello','SomePageHello',
    '/SomePageGoodbye','SomePageGoodbye',


    )

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class SomePageHello:
    def GET(self):
        user_data = web.input(name="no data")
        return "<h1> Hello " + user_data.name + "</h1>"

class SomePageGoodbye:
    def GET(self):
        user_data = web.input(name="no data")
        return "<h1> Goodbye " + user_data.name + "</h1>"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The url should be something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/SomePageHello?name=dasfasd
```